# command fails because needs to be root

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, vagrant

I'm testing thi project :

> https://github.com/sayems/kubernetes.resources/

And just for my understanding i commented out the ansible provisioning in the vagant part :

> https://github.com/sayems/kubernetes.resources/blob/master/k8s-vagrant/Vagrantfile#L34

to

> https://github.com/sayems/kubernetes.resources/blob/master/k8s-vagrant/Vagrantfile#L41

Then ran :

```
vagrant up
```

Witch start a non provisioned cluster a wanted

Then :

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.ini
```

But I'm getting this error :

> TASK [token : Copy join command to local file]
>   ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************* fatal: [k8s-master]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to get information on
>   remote file (./join-command): sudo: il est nécessaire de saisir un mot
>   de passe\n"}

If i understand it needs to be root to execute this command :

> https://github.com/sayems/kubernetes.resources/blob/master/k8s-vagrant/roles/join/tasks/main.yml

But we are supposed to be root :

> https://github.com/sayems/kubernetes.resources/blob/master/k8s-vagrant/playbook.yml

can anyone help or have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to run it with `sudo`. Modules like copy expect to be available as the user running Ansible.

[Reference](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/41056)